# Changing child's class when parent is clicked with jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, parent

I'm admittedly completely unfamiliar with jQuery. I've snooped around here a bit trying to find snippets to help me accomplish my goal, and I can't find anything.

My markup is such:

```
<a href="#" id="local-song-button" class="music sm2_link">
    <i id="button-toggle" class="fa fa-play-circle-o blue"></i>
</a>
```

I'm running a script that changes the `local-song-button <a>` depending on the event. It can be `sm2_link` for an inactive song playing, `sm2_playing` while a song is playing and `sm2_paused` when paused.

Now, the problem I'm running into is I'd like to change the class of `button-toggle` depending on which class the `local-song-button` is taking. I can't seem to figure out the correct way to do this. I've looked into `toggleClass()` as well but I feel like I'll need an `if()` statement somewhere? This is all I could come up with:

```
if ($('#local-song-button').hasClass('sm2_playing')){
   $('#button-toggle').removeClass('fa-play-circle-o');
   $('#button-toggle').addClass('fa-pause');
}elseif ($('#local-song-button').hasClass('sm2_paused')){
   $('#button-toggle').removeClass('fa-pause');
   $('#button-toggle').addClass('fa-play-circle-o');
}
```

And that's definitely not working.

Comment: Except `else if` code seems fine. On what event do you trigger this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, you missed the space in between `else` and `if`, you could also use `toggleClass`.

```
function togglePlayButton()
{
    var loadingBtn = $('#local-song-button');
    var toggleBtn = $('#button-toggle');

    if(loadingBtn.hasClass('sm2_playing') || loadingBtn.hasClass('sm2_link'))
    {
      toggleBtn.toggleClass('fa-play-circle-o fa-pause');
    }
    else if(loadingBtn.hasClass('sm2_paused'))
    {
      toggleBtn.toggleClass('fa-pause fa-play-circle-o');
    }
}
```

Comment: I've used your code in a function and am calling it like so: `$('#local-song-button').click(togglePlayButton());`

There is no changes and no errors in the console. Am I going about this the wrong way? On pageload the only class on `#local-song-button`, on first click is when the `sm2_playing` is appended/toggled to `sm2_paused`. Will this code work if that's how the classes are appended?

[Here is the page in question](http://badjams.com/t/test-page.html) if you'd like to view it in action.

Comment: I have updated my answer to work with your `togglePlayButton()` function.

Comment: Works splendidly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you use firebug or chrome developer tools, you can see this error from the console tab:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

It's because of your `elseif`. The correct way is to use `else if`. Fix it and it should be fine.

Also note that from the provided HTML markup in your question, the `#local-song-button` anchor only has class `sm2_link`, not either `sm2_playing` or `sm2_paused`

Comment: Ah! Thank you. Another script I'm running changes/appends those other two classes on depending on the song being played or paused.